# Are traditional masculinity norms optimal in terms of mating preferences?

Tags: gender

Are traditional masculinity norms optimal in terms of mating preferences?

In other words, do women prefer men who exhibit those traditional gender norms of masculinity?

Traditional gender norms of masculinity: strongness, muscularity, braveness, performance, combatitivity, sense of honor, emotional inhibition, sense of challenge, and sense of power; to which are added the ideal of the warrior (Gazalé 2017, 2018).

I think this is not clearly what points the last research on this issue (Grammer & Sainani 2015; Walter et al. 2020).

"Good financial prospects" does not seem exactly synonymous to "braveness", "performance", "combatitivity", "sense of honor", and "kindness" is not very compatible with "the ideal of the warrior", "sense of power" and "emotional inhibition".

"Physical attractiveness" is neither not the same as "strongness" and "muscularity".

**References:**

Gazalé, O. (2017). Le mythe de la virilité. *Robert Laffont*.

Gazalé, O. (2018). Oliva Gazalé, auteure du "Mythe de la virilité". The boys club Episode 6. Les Podcasts de Fab Florent. Youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5zugeciaY8&t=1929s

Grammer, K., & Sainani, K. L. (2015). Q&A: Karl Grammer. Innate attractions. *Nature*, 526(7572), S11-S11.

Walter, K. V., Conroy-Beam, D., Buss, D. M., Asao, K., Sorokowska, A., Sorokowski, P., ... & Zupančič, M. (2020). Sex differences in mate preferences across 45 countries: A large-scale replication. *Psychological Science*, 31(4), 408-423.